# JSuggestField in Applet error

Tags: java, jsp, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I wrote an applet that executing very well. I used JSuggestField for autocomplete. Then I wanted to use this applet in a JSP project. When I run the web project , applet did not execute on the browser and has given errors.  My JSP codes are ;

```
        <body>
            <applet archive="KitapAraApplet.jar,suggest.jar" code="KitapAra.class"
                    height="250" width="300"></applet>
        </body>
```

the error is :

```
java.lang..NoClassDefFounderError: ch/rakudave/suggest/JSuggestField
```

Comment: What Jar is `JSuggestField` located in?

Comment: in libs folder netbeans. I located it in that folder.

Comment: What is the NAME of the Jar in the `lib` folder of Netbeans?  Is it called `KitapAraApplet.jar` or `suggest.jar` or something else?

Comment: I must use KitapApplet.jar for executing applet in the web project.

Comment: Not only does your last comment not answer my question, but it really makes no sense to me at all.  I feel I am unable to help you, at this point.

Comment: It is calling KitapApplet.jar. siktir git

Comment: I did'nt understand that what you want yarak kafa

Comment: I have written KitapApplet.jar mal mısın göt kafalı triplere girme